# How do i align my video to the top left corner, what is creating those spacing above the video and below?

Tags: html, css

Im trying to put a video in a container using flexbox but ive noticed that there is some spacing above the video and below it and i want it to align to the box perfectly.
https://codepen.io/betablue/pen/NmJPqG
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvtQk.jpg

CSS is in codepen.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  border: 3px dashed black;
  width: 750px;
  height: 750px;
}

.container>div>video {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <video width="400" height="400" autoplay Loop muted controls>
  <source src="Watervid.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
  </div>




  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Converted your pen to snippet. it looks like you have an extra `  </div>` just before closing the `body` tag.

Comment: Thank you, but that didnt solve it :)

Comment: running the code (Click "RUN CODE SNIPPET") dosent reproduce the error.
i guess there are other factors involved, you should post more of your css.

Comment: yeah im not sure but i solved it, i deleted width="400" height="400" added a class="item-1" and in css targeted item-1 {width:60%} and that solved it. It doesnt define the video by 400 pixels but by a percentage of the container pixel settings.

Answer (score 0):

Try this CSS, you´re not using flex-blox properties correctly :

```
  .container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 3px dashed black; 
  width: 750px; 
  height: 750px;
  }

   .container > div > video {
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
   }
```